# How to make sampler?

Tags: software, live, live-sound

I was on a concert with orchestra and there was a player performing sampler on the keyboard.
The player played from the score which had a standard notation. However when a tone is pressed on the keyboard it produces a sampled sound. 
The keyboard was connected to a computer and than to the amplifier (speakers).

How to make that set-up?
What software is used to map (link) these sounds to the keyboard?
I know how to make sounds, but I don't know how to make a set-up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are known as [digital samplers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sampler_(musical_instrument)) and most [Digital Audio Workstations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_audio_workstation) come with their own, native sampler.
For example, FL Studio's native sampler would be the [Sampler Channel](https://www.image-line.com/support/FLHelp/html/chansettings_sampler.htm); Logic Pro's native sampler is [EXS24](https://help.apple.com/logicpro-instruments/mac/10.2/index.html?localePath=en.lproj#lgsifc860d24).

To trigger the digital sampler by the means of an external device, the hardware must be [MIDI-compatible](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIDI_controller). In this particular setup, the keyboard player was using some kind of MIDI keyboard to interact with the software on his computer. It's important to note that MIDI controllers do not produce sound on their own, they simply interact with music notation software installed on the computers.

Hardware samplers certainly do exist though if all of this doesn't sound like your cup of tea, but their use in live performances is dwindling as everything in this day and age is transitioning to digital.